# using if(any()) in a for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, any

I would like to generate a loop as such:

```
group1 = c(1,3,7,25)

for (ii in 1:25){
    if (ii == any(group1)){test = 5} else {test=1}
}
```

I am receiving a warning about coercing my argument of type 'double' to logical.  The result is that only my else statement is being used.  What does that mean and how do I fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: you're asking for `any()` to determine if any value your vector `group1` is true... I think you may want `any(ii %in% group1)`.

Comment: @Justin Maybe the `any` isn't even needed at all...?

Comment: @joran by jove I think you might be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you do want. Possibly

```
 test <- c(1,5)[1+(1:25) %in% group1]
```

Same result as:

```
test <- ifelse( 1:25 %in% group1, 5, 1)
```

Oh, OK, i'll make the `for`-loopy version, too:

```
test <- integer(25)
for (ii in 1:25){
   if (ii %in% group1){test[ii] <- 5} else {test[ii] <- 1}
                }
test
```

Comment: that works exactly! thanks DWin!  you're right, I wasn't clear that my output for test was supposed to be a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong any function

```
any(iterable)
```

Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

Comment: @OzanDeniz: This doesn't make sense. There is only one `any` function. `any()` also returns FALSE if `iterable == 0` or if iterable=c(0,0,0,0) or if all of the arguments are `FALSE` but NOT if they are `False`